# How to add <select> floating label without using required

Tags: html, css, validation, html-select

I went through most of the questions related to this. But I couldn't find out the solution. I have provided the code so far. My requirement is to remove the `required` from the `<select>` and work this as it is. If I remove it at the moment, this will not work as expected.

I know this is really possible via JavaScript/jQuery but I want to do this with CSS.

```css
label.input {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span.input__label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #828282;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 35px;
}

.input:active::after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.input__field:invalid {
  color: transparent;
  transition: 200ms color linear 100ms;
}

.input__field:valid + .input__label, .input__field:focus:valid + .input__label {
    transform: translate(0.5em, -10%);
    transition: 200ms transform ease-out;
    color: #000;
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.input__label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: 200ms transform ease-out 200ms;
  will-change: transform;
}

select.form-select {
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #828282;
    display: inline-block;
}

select.form-select option {
    color: #828282;
}

.form-select:focus {
    border-color: #dcd9d6;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

form select {
    width: 240px;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 16px 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #828282;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dcd9d6;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label class="input">
    <select name="max-price" class="input__field form-select" id="maxPrice" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
        <option value="100,000">100,000</option>
        <option value="200,000">200,000</option>
        <option value="300,000">300,000</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input__label">Max Price</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's work for you !!!

You need to add onchange event in select.

```
onchange=" this.dataset.select = this.value;
```

```css
       label.input {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span.input__label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #828282;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 35px;
}

.input:active::after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.input__field:invalid {
  color: transparent;
  transition: 200ms color linear 100ms;
}


.input__label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: 200ms transform ease-out 200ms;
  will-change: transform;
  opacity: 0;
}

select.form-select {
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #828282;
    display: inline-block;
}

select.form-select option {
    color: #828282;
}

.form-select:focus {
    border-color: #dcd9d6;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

form select {
    width: 240px;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 16px 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #828282;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dcd9d6;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
        
select[data-select]+ .input__label {
    transform: translate(0.5em, -10%);
    transition: 200ms transform ease-out;
    color: #000;
    top: 5px;
    left: 2px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label class="input">
        <select onchange=" this.dataset.select = this.value; " name="max-price" class="input__field form-select" id="maxPrice">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Max Price</option>
            <option value="100,000">100,000</option>
            <option value="200,000">200,000</option>
            <option value="300,000">300,000</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input__label">Max Price</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I seriously like this solution. Assume these values are dynamic values from PHP. How are you going to manage then?

Comment: @WP Learner
I have update my previous code please check it.